# Computing normals option not working using CloudCompare GUI

Tags: las, point-cloud, usgs, cloudcompare

I am trying to compute normals for a pointcloud I had cropped from a USGS lidar map. It is a .las file, but it might be missing some header values, but it does get imported into Cloud compare without any problems. But I am not able to click on the compute normals button, it stays unavailable. Is it because of the pointcloud or should I install anything further to enable normal computing.

I am attaching the console result while I import my las file. Would any of the missing fields be necessary to compute normals?

[image]